# Regex Extract String Between 2 Text - Ending in ()

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to isolate the text between 2 Text place holders in a  string

Anything between the 3 letters below and ending in **()** - brackets

Example

```
Kwl  ThisString ()
Kwl   String_2()
kwl   string_3_as_well()
kwl maybethisverylongstringaswell()
```

I have tried many combinations including

```
Kwl([!\)]*\))
```

Comment: `Kwl\s?(\w+)\(\)` https://regex101.com/r/eT2dA2/1

Comment: So the leading 3 letters must be `Kwl`, case sensitive? and there must be at least one space after?

Comment: What is the regex flavor?

Comment: I apologize -  I have never heard of a regex flavor. I am trying to use this in powershell if that's any help

Comment: Please show your code. To get the first match, you just need to use [regex]::match and access the value.

Comment: $Pat1 = [regex]'(?i)(?<=kwl ).*?(?= *\(\))'

Comment: Folks, I apologise  - I am a powershell newbie too , I am not sure how to get the first match

Comment: You could just obtain what you need with `$s = 'Kwl  ThisString ()' //
$s = $s -replace "(?si)^.*?\bkwl\b(.*?)\(\).*", '$1' // 
$s = $s.Trim()`. Much simpler than matching, you could replace with a simpler expression than Bohemian's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match your target:

```
(?i)(?<=kwl ).*?(?= *\(\))
```

Explanation:

- `(?i)` means "ignore case" (so all variants of `kwl` match)
- `(?<=kwl )` is a look behind assertion
- `.*?` is a reluctant quantifier (matches as little as possible)
- `(?= *\(\))` is a look ahead assertion

Look arounds don't capture, so the *entire* match is your target.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/3Rq86V6SNz).

This will also match if the target has brackets, like this:

```
kWl including backets ( ) like this ()
```

---

If reluctant quantifiers are not supported, use this:

```
(?i)(?<=kwl )(.(?! *\(\))*.(?= *\(\))
```

Comment: Great solution ... +1

Comment: Using lookarounds with lazy dot matching loses to a capture group based regex written acc. to the unroll the loop technique.

Comment: Also, if it is Qt, that regex flavor does not support lazy quantifiers.

Comment: @wiktor see edit for work around not using reluctant quantifier

Comment: Bohemian thank you very much this looks awesome, is there any way to match it to only the first time it finds the ()    - somewhere in the files there may be another set , I apologise I did not think of that before :)

Comment: Why did you set a quantifier to a lookahead? :) BTW, it might be a good idea to use lookaround based solution in PowerShell (it depends on the current OP code).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
^[K|k]wl\s+(\w+)\s?\(\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/iA1pI3/3

Comment: fyi `\w` includes underscore, so `[\w_]+` is identical with `\w+`

Comment: @Bohemian Are you sure? I read somewhere `\w` means this `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: @Shafizadeh I am 100% sure. `\w` is identical with `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: @Shafizadeh http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html, second paragraph: "`\w` stands for "word character". It always matches the ASCII characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits."

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but the `!` may not be doing what you think it is in the parser you are using. `^` is typically used for character-class negation in many modern RegEx parsers:

```
Kwl[^)]*
```

You should also escape your parenthesis with a backslash `\` as they are special characters outside of a character class. (As a side note, the parser for stackoverflow also seems to consume backslashes in text, in case you were using one and are wondering why it didn't show up)

```
Kwl[^)]*\\)
```

If you specifically want the match to end with `()`, you should end your greedy looping once you find a `(`:

```
Kwl[^(]*\\(\\)
```

Depending on the application you may also want to use `[Kk]`. A case-sensitive parser will not match those lower-case kwl's otherwise. (It does depend though; I know Notepad++'s is case-insensitive for some reason).

The best advice I can give would be to find a list of the specific character set for the RegEx parser you are using.